# Transform discrete data into continuous

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, data-analysis

How do I transform a discrete sample into a continuous distribution.

Let's suppose I have a collection of points (time, price of stock) for instance. I would like to transform it into a distribution (price of stock, probability). How do I do that? Should I need to use the Central Limit Theorem, even if the distribution probably won't be a normal? I mean, I would not like to normalize it.

For small amount of data, it's fairly easy to do it by hand and then graph. However, for a gigantic sample, it's almost impossible.
Thanks

Comment: One way is that you can construct a histogram based on a subset of your data (if you say it's gigantic) to get a sense of how the data is distributed, then you can fit a probability distribution based on your observations.

Comment: Fitting a continuous function to a discrete number of data points will always require an arbitrary choice as to how you stitch the pieces together. You typically need some reason to choose one or the other depending on the problem you're studying.

Comment: @CyclotomicField and Alexandru, I would like to transform this discrete sample into a continuous so as to calculate probabilities easier. Let's suppose my set fits in a distribution D, how should I calculate the probability? Just integration right?

Comment: Do you mean something like the empirical distribution which approximates the distribution of the sample? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function

Comment: @delivery101 hmm that seems interesting. Thank you